# Tail Rot affecting other limbs?

Tags: health, reptiles, diseases, lizards, bearded-dragon

So, I have two Beardies one male one not entirely sure, Blaze and Nermy. But anyways they seem to have tail rot on there legs as well. Can this happen

Comment: Can you post photos?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can happen.

It's called tail rot because it's most commonly seen on the tail. What happens is, while molting, the skin doesn't fully come off the tip of the lizard's tail. So during the next molt, there's a ring of dead skin holding on to the tip of the tail that can also prevent that piece of skin from coming off.

Because lizards molt when they grow, that means with each molt, the ring of dead skin grows tighter, making it more and more likely to stop more skin from properly coming off, and creates what is essentially a tourniquet on the lizard's tail, cutting off blood circulation.

You can identify tail rot by the skin being a darker color than the rest of the body. Even more so than the dull patches you see while they're molting. Usually it's a clear cutoff between healthy tail, and dark, "rotting" tail. If not taken care of, the parts of the tail being constricted by old skin will become deformed and eventually self-amputate.

This same process can happen with a lizard's feet. It will start with skin not coming off the lizard's toes, and then building up to envelope it's entire legs.

Because it's already in the stages where you've noticed it, you should really take your dragon to the nearest reptile/exotic animal veterinarian to get it looked at.They'll be able to tell you if it's currently at a stage where the condition can be mitigated, or if they need to amputate the limb(s) before they begin to cause your dragon too much discomfort.

In the future, during each molt, it's best to give your dragon a lukewarm bath to help loosen molting skin. You can massage the skin with your fingers, or a soft-bristled tooth brush if you're concerned about an area during a molt, but you should never try and force molting skin off as you might damage the growing tissue underneath accidentally.